# Clustering and Dirichlet process' parameter

Tags: bayesian, clustering, nonparametric, prior, dirichlet-process

I am reading a paper in which they describe a bayesian model in which the prior $a_i$ is defined as a Dirichlet Process (DP). They say: "We use a DP to find the optimal $a_i$ via clustering".
Later on they write: "In order to divide our customers in clusters we consider the posterior estimates of the non parametric $a_i$ that induces a partition on the dataset. For each iteration [of the chain] we have a partition of our clients with respect to number of clusters"

Can someone explain? I see a contradiction here, because as I undestrand it, DP can be used for clustering in the sense that I claim that two customers are in the same cluster if tehy have the same $a_i$. But then I don't undestrand the first quote.

Comment: You'll need to write a little more about the DP model you're reviewing, as your notation is unclear.  For example, what is $a_i$?  What is $i$?  An index on the customers or on the clusters?

Comment: $i$ is an index on the customers. $a_i$ is one of the prior parameters for each client.
I have $y_{ij}$ = Poisson($w_{ij}$)
$w_{ij}$ = f(x, $b_j$) + $a_i$,  

$a_i$=G  

G=DP( )  

[= stands for tilde, soz]

Comment: FYI, tilde is \sim as in $\sim$