# Dirichlet process and clustering

Tags: bayesian, clustering, prior, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

How does clustering with a Dirichlet process as prior work? I am confused as to if the parameter $\alpha_i$ $\sim$ DP is found via clustering or is used to cluster. I undestrand how it can be used to cluster, but I have been told it is found via clustering, but I'm not sure.

Similar question to this
$a_i$ is $\alpha_i$ here

[Clustering and Dirichlet process' parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326640/clustering-and-dirichlet-process-parameter).

Comment: A very broad overview is given here, https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~teh/research/npbayes/Teh2010a.pdf, another that goes into some more detail including covering the dirichlet distribution first is here, http://mayagupta.org/publications/FrigyikKapilaGuptaIntroToDirichlet.pdf